# Sum of dynamically generated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am generating monthly attendance of students.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_FOR_FACULTY
@startdate DATE,  
@enddate DATE,
@collegecode nvarchar(10),
@coursecode nvarchar(10),
@subjectcode nvarchar(10)

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @query as varchar(MAX);

with cte (startdate) as 
(
    select @startdate startdate
    union all 
    select dateadd(DD, 1, startdate) 
    from cte
    where startdate < @enddate
)

select @query = coalesce(@query, '') + 
              N',coalesce(MAX(CASE when A.[Date] = ''' + 
              cast(cte.startdate as nvarchar(20)) + 
              N''' THEN Convert(varchar(10),A.[Attendance]) end), ''-'') ' + 
              quotename(convert(char(2), cte.startdate,104))
from cte
where datename(weekday, cte.startdate) <> 'Sunday';

set @query = 'Select S.RollNo AS [Roll No],Concat(FirstName,'' '',LastName) Name' + @query + ',Concat(sum(Attendance),''/'',count(Attendance)) Total
              from Attendance A, Student S, UserDetails U
              where A.EnrollmentNo=S.EnrollmentNo and S.EnrollmentNo=U.userID and S.CollegeCode=''' + @collegecode + ''' and A.CourseCode=''' + @coursecode + ''' and A.SubjectCode =''' + @subjectcode +''' 
              and A.Date between ''' + Convert(nvarchar,@startdate) + ''' and ''' + Convert(nvarchar,@enddate) + '''
              Group By S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName';


Execute (@query)
END
```

This is working fine to generate the date-wise records of attendance but there can be multiple records of the same date.

In that case, sum of the attendance should be displayed for that particular date.

So, what should I change in @query to achieve the desired outcome ?

**Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Attendance (EnrollmentNo varchar(50),
                          SubjectCode varchar(10),
                          [Date] datetime,
                          Attendance numeric(1,0),
                          CourseCode varchar(10),
                          FacultyId varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #Attendance
VALUES ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180201',0,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180201',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180201',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180202',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180202',2,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
       ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180202',0,'BSCCS','Fac101');

CREATE TABLE #Student (EnrollmentNo varchar(50),
                       RollNo numeric(3,0),
                       CollegeCode varchar(10),
                       CourseCode varchar(10),
                       [year] int);
INSERT INTO #Student
VALUES ('DDU-320/12',38,'DDUC','BSCCS',2012);

CREATE TABLE #UserDetail (userID varchar(50),
                          Firstname varchar(50),
                          LastName varchar(50),
                          Gender varchar (6),
                          [Address] varchar(500),
                          Phone varchar(10));
INSERT INTO #UserDetail
VALUES ('DDU-320/12','Suyash','Gupta','Male','Lucknow',9817271);
GO
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+---------+--------------+----+----+-------+
| Roll No |     Name     | 01 | 02 | Total |
+---------+--------------+----+----+-------+
|      38 | Suyash Gupta |  2 |  3 |     5 |
+---------+--------------+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: you will firstly need to get the totals per day with some grouping and then pivot the values to get the total if you want the output like that.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(s.RollNo) RollNo, MIN(ud.Firstname) + ' ' + MIN(ud.LastName) Name, SUM(a.Attendance) Attendance, a.Date FROM #UserDetail AS ud INNER JOIN #Student AS s ON s.EnrollmentNo = ud.EnrollmentNo INNER JOIN #Attendance AS a ON a.EnrollmentNo = s.EnrollmentNo GROUP BY a.Date` that should get you part way there.

Comment: In #UserDetail table userID field which is in the same data type with EnrollmentNo is missing in data model you shared with us. OR in WHERE clause, use "S.EnrollmentNo=U.EnrollmentNo" instead of "S.EnrollmentNo=U.UserId"

Comment: @Eralper Sorry, it was a typo. EnrollmentNo in userDetail was actually userID. Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here is how your end result should look like when code is compiled:

> I changed your Test data from UserDetails to UserDetail. And then instead of where s.EnrollmentNo = u.UserId i wrote s.EnrollmentNo = u.EnrollmentID
>
> Furthermore i used joins instead of where clause
>
> I also didnt do anything with your total as it pretty obvious that you only need to remove your count and slash /

```
SELECT S.RollNo AS [Roll No]
    ,CONCAT (
        FirstName
        ,' '
        ,LastName
        ) NAME
    ,coalesce(sum(CASE 
                WHEN A.[Date] = '2018-02-01'
                    THEN A.[Attendance]
                END), 0) [01]
    ,coalesce(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN A.[Date] = '2018-02-02'
                    THEN  A.[Attendance]
                END), 0) [02]

    ,CONCAT (
        sum(Attendance)
        ,'/'
        ,count(Attendance)
        ) Total
FROM Attendance A
    inner join Student S on A.EnrollmentNo = S.EnrollmentNo
    inner join UserDetail U on S.EnrollmentNo = U.EnrollmentNo
WHERE
     S.CollegeCode = 'DDUC'
    AND A.CourseCode = 'BSCCS'
    AND A.SubjectCode = 'CSHT101'
    AND A.DATE BETWEEN '2018-02-01'
        AND '2018-02-02'
GROUP BY S.RollNo
    ,U.FirstName
    ,U.LastName
```

**So you SP would like this**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_FOR_FACULTY
@startdate DATE,  
@enddate DATE,
@collegecode nvarchar(10),
@coursecode nvarchar(10),
@subjectcode nvarchar(10)

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @query as varchar(MAX);



  with cte (startdate) as  (
    select @startdate startdate
    union all 
    select dateadd(DD, 1, startdate) 
    from cte
    where startdate < @enddate )

select @query = coalesce(@query, '') + 
              N',coalesce(sum(CASE when A.[Date] = ''' + 
              cast(cte.startdate as nvarchar(20)) + 
              N''' THEN A.[Attendance] end), 0) ' + 
              quotename(convert(char(2), cte.startdate,104)) from cte where datename(weekday, cte.startdate) <> 'Sunday';



set @query = 'Select S.RollNo AS [Roll No],Concat(FirstName,'' '',LastName) Name' + @query + ',Concat(sum(Attendance),''/'',count(Attendance)) Total
              from Attendance A inner join Student S on A.EnrollmentNo = S.EnrollmentNo
        inner join UserDetail U on S.EnrollmentNo = U.EnrollmentNo
              where S.CollegeCode=''' + @collegecode + ''' and A.CourseCode=''' + @coursecode + ''' and A.SubjectCode =''' + @subjectcode +''' 
              and A.Date between ''' + Convert(nvarchar,@startdate) + ''' and ''' + Convert(nvarchar,@enddate) + '''
              Group By S.RollNo,U.FirstName,U.LastName';

PRINT @query Execute (@query)
```

**Result with 8 days just to show what happends when they are not equal**

[image]

Comment: I wanted '-' instead of 0. In that case, sum would not work.

Comment: Oh okay. But i Dont understand Why you want a string value in an int col. You Will also have an issume when you sum then all. Makes no sense

Comment: Actually, 0, here, denotes that the student was not present in the class and I wanted '-' to denote that class was not held during that particular day.

Answer (score 2):

Using your sample data (before it was corrected) this will give you the answer you need, but it will still need adapting to work dynamically:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT
    s.RollNo,
    u.LastName + ' ' + u.Firstname AS [Name],
    DATEPART(DAY, a.[Date]) AS [day],
    SUM(a.Attendance) AS Attendance
FROM
    #Student s
    INNER JOIN #UserDetail u ON u.EnrollmentNo = s.EnrollmentNo
    INNER JOIN #Attendance a ON a.EnrollmentNo = s.EnrollmentNo
GROUP BY
    s.RollNo,
    u.LastName + ' ' + u.Firstname,
    DATEPART(DAY, a.[Date]))
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT SUM(Attendance) FROM x WHERE x.RollNo = p.RollNo) AS total
FROM 
    x 
    PIVOT (SUM(Attendance) FOR [Day] IN ([1], [2])) p;
```

Results:

```
RollNo  Name            1   2   total
38      Gupta Suyash    2   3   5
```

Comment: I prefer to leave out the dynamic sql as well, I would use a windowed function over the group, but the output is the same. sum(Attendance) over(partition by a.EnrollmentNo, SubjectCode, date order by [Date])

Comment: Your missing out the dynamic values of dates if he expands his date filter. Therefore your pivot should at least be dynamic to count in for how many days it spands over.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Richard Hansell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1666276/richard-hansell)'s reply, 
I'd use a dynamic pivot to include all the days on the date period provided to stored procedure and I'd use Grouping Sets to sum up the total

here is the query:

```
        /*Creating the sample data*/
                    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Attendance') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Attendance
        IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Student') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Student
        IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#UserDetail') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #UserDetail

        CREATE TABLE #Attendance (EnrollmentNo varchar(50),
                                  SubjectCode varchar(10),
                                  [Date] datetime,
                                  Attendance numeric(1,0),
                                  CourseCode varchar(10),
                                  FacultyId varchar(50));

        INSERT INTO #Attendance
        VALUES ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180201',0,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
               ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180201',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
               ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180201',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
               ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180202',1,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
               ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180202',2,'BSCCS','Fac101'),
               ('DDU-322/12','CSHT100','20180202',2,'BSCCO','Fac101'),
               ('DDU-320/12','CSHT101','20180202',0,'BSCCS','Fac101');

        CREATE TABLE #Student (EnrollmentNo varchar(50),
                               RollNo numeric(3,0),
                               CollegeCode varchar(10),
                               CourseCode varchar(10),
                               [year] int);
        INSERT INTO #Student
        VALUES ('DDU-320/12',38,'DDUC','BSCCS',2012),
               ('DDU-322/12',39,'DDUC','BSCCO',2012);

        CREATE TABLE #UserDetail (userID varchar(50),
                                  Firstname varchar(50),
                                  LastName varchar(50),
                                  Gender varchar (6),
                                  [Address] varchar(500),
                                  Phone varchar(10));
        INSERT INTO #UserDetail
        VALUES ('DDU-320/12','Suyash','Gupta','Male','Lucknow',9817271),
               ('DDU-322/12','Gupta','Suyash','Male','Lucknow',9817279);
        GO

        SET NOCOUNT ON 
        IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T
        /*These are the Parameters for you stored procedure*/
        DECLARE @startdate DATE ='2018-02-01 00:00:00.000'  
        DECLARE @enddate DATE= '2018-02-02 00:00:00.000'
        DECLARE @collegecode nvarchar(10)= 'DDUC'
        DECLARE @coursecode nvarchar(10) = 'BSCCS'
        DECLARE @subjectcode nvarchar(10) ='CSHT101'

        ;
        with cte (startdate) as 
        (
            select @startdate startdate
            union all 
            select dateadd(DD, 1, startdate) 
            from cte
            where startdate < @enddate
        )

        SELECT startdate ,  CAST(RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEPART(DAY,[startdate])),2) AS VARCHAR(20)) startdate_Day
        INTO #T
        FROM cte

        DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        SELECT @Cols += ',' + QUOTENAME(startdate_Day)
        FROM #T
        GROUP BY startdate_Day

        SET @Cols= STUFF(@Cols, 1,1,'') + ',[Total]'

        DECLARE @Pvt NVARCHAR(MAX)=
        '
        ;WITH Aggr as 
        (
        SELECT  s.RollNo , d.Firstname + '' '' + d.LastName [Name] , a.[Date],  T.startdate_Day,
        SUM(Attendance) Attendance
        FROM #T T
        LEFT JOIN #Attendance A 
        ON T.startdate = A.[Date]
        JOIN #Student S 
        ON A.EnrollmentNo = S.EnrollmentNo
        JOIN #UserDetail D
        ON S.EnrollmentNo = D.userID
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS  (
                        (s.RollNo ,d.Firstname + '' '' + d.LastName , a.[Date] ,T.startdate_Day ) , (s.RollNo , d.Firstname + '' '' + d.LastName ))

        )
        SELECT RollNo , [Name] , '+@Cols+'
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT RollNo, [Name]  ,  ISNULL(startdate_Day,''Total'') startdate_Day , Attendance
         FROM Aggr
         ) Main 
         PIVOT
            (
            MAX(Attendance) FOR startdate_Day IN ('+@Cols+')
            ) P
        '
        EXEC sp_executesql @Pvt
```